# In Azure Data Factory, how do i create a string expressions made up of a Paramater, string literal and function, in the web UI

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to have an expression equal to MyParmater + '_' + utcnow()

My current attempt is: @{pipeline().parameters.Col}_{utcnow()}
but iy fails

Answer (score 1):

Use the *[concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat)* function:

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.Col,'_',utcNow())
```